# how to select a particular row?

Tags: jquery

I have a table with id as "mytable" and have lots of rows in it...

I want to select a row with id ="row_100" in it using jquery..

how to do this..

code

```
function highlight_tran(tranid) 
{
    var rowpos = $('#'+tranid).position();
    $('#trtable').scrollTop(rowpos.top); 
}
```

where trtable is the container id of the table

tranid is id of the tr, here tranid is the one user wants to see...so it may not be seen as this is scrollable table, to make it view i am doing this function, for autoscrolling...

now its working to the last row, but after that when we select any top rows autoscroll will not move above to the exact TR position althoughh the "tranid" passed is correct...I am messed up with this...
is there any another neat solution to achieve this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have multiple tables with mass amount of rows you can use jquery [Descendant Selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) by doing something like:

## Table

```
<table id="table_1">
   <tr><td>1</td></tr>
   <tr><td>2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>3</td></tr>
   <!-- .... -->
   <tr><td>102</td></tr>
   <tr><td>103</td></tr>
</table>
```

## jQuery

```
$("#table_1 tr:eq(100)").css(/*...*/);
```

or if your rows have an ID and-or your using live element insertions,

```
$("#table_1 tr#row_100").css(/*...*/);
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use the JQuery selector?

```
$("#row_100");
```

If you are selecting a certain row in different tables, maybe you should consider assigning `id` for your tables, and `class` to the row:

```
 <table id="first_part">
       ...
       <tr class="special">...</tr>
       ...
   </table>

   <table id="second_part">
      ...
      <tr class="special">...</tr>
   </table>
```

And then select using something like `$("#first_part .special")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a [#id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) here (which is the fastest way as well), like this:

```
$("#row_100");
```

Comment: @soorajthomas - whoa now, that's a problem, IDs need to be unique *in the page*, they should never be repeated.  Can you paste your markup?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness, if row_100 means the 100th row, you can also do this

`$("tr:eq(99)")`
 - which would select the 100th instance of tr if you've got more than one table, us the table's id before the tr:

`$("#myTable tr:eq(99)")`

**EDIT**

Okay so I've tested this and it at least selects the correct row given

```
var selector = "#trtable tr:eq(" + tranid + ")";
$(selector).scrolltop(this.top);
```

Comment: var rowpos = $('#'+tranid).position();

$('#trtable').scrollTop(rowpos.top);

Comment: that is to autoscroll to the selected row in the scrollable table, but for some tr's its not working..

Comment: thanks alex.. so if row id is dynamic, then how will I use urs $("#myTable tr:eq(99)") for tat, suppose id variable is tranid...

Comment: I've edited my answer, there's a little more footwork involved but this does select correctly

Comment: hi Alex,  I applied, as you gave, but its not scrolling to the tr!

Comment: Well the first step is to make sure it's grabbing the correct row, change scrolltop to something like .css("background", "red") or something that will make the row stand out.

Comment: If that grabs the correct row check the scrolltop code, I've never been able to use it myself so I could very well be using it incorrectly